# Responsive Navigation Menu CSS replace Jquery perhaps

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, navigation

I'm trying to create a responsive navigation menu that shrinks when window size shrinks. I've gotten it to work in jquery and css but it's slow on mobile devices and I read that it's better to code it in CSS only but I haven't been able to find a solution to it. Here is what I currently have for jquery, html and css. Any help is appreciated

Jquery Code:

```
    $(function() {
    var menu        = $('#top_menu');
        menu        = $('nav ul');
        menuHeight  = menu.height();

    $(top_menu).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 720 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/forum">Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/aboutus">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" id="top_menu">Menu</a>
        </nav>
```

CSS Code:

```
    nav a#top_menu {
    display: block;
    background: url('../images/main_logo.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 20px 17px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;   
}

nav a#top_menu:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #305f6d;
}

nav a#top_menu:after {
    content:"";
    background: url('../images/mini.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this with Pure CSS, then you should really look at Navigataur (https://coderwall.com/p/sujd_w) which is a Pure CSS solution instead of using jQuery.

Setup is as follows:

1. Reference the stylesheet inbetween your `<head>` tags like so:

> ```
> <html>
> <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navigataur.css"></head>
> <body>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

1. Edit your the names of your CSS elements if any of the element names below are already used in your css file

To work out of the box, you will need the following adjustments to your markup (classes can be changed in the stylesheet if you use something different):

- An outer `<div>` with a class of `header`
- An input[type=checkbox] with an ID of `toggle` and label[for=toggle] with a class of `toggle` just above your list menu.
- A list menu (either ul or ol) with a class of `menu`

Change your

1. HTML code (simplest example possible):

> ```
> <input type='checkbox' id='toggle'/> <label for='toggle'
> class='toggle'></label>
> <ul class="menu">
>     <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
>     <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li> 
> </ul>
> ```

And that's it, you're done!

Here is a demo of Navigataur in action: http://micjamking.github.com/Navigataur/